# Knife.rb configuration syntax

Tags: knife

What is the difference between knife configurations with the '=' symbol and without the '=' symbol.

Ex:

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

vs

```
log_level                :debug
node_name                "admin"
```

Comment: Ex: 
current_dir = File.dirname(FILE)

vs

log_level                    :debug 
node_name                "admin"

Answer (score 0):

`current_dir = ...` is plain ruby code. It does not set any configuration options. But you can compute some values and use it later for example:

```
cookbook_path "#{current_dir}/cookbooks"
```